# Why my datalist is displaying only first image?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have db which contains products with columns: image1, image2, image3. I'm displaying this datalist and only first picture occurs there. On the others images I see that redirection is fine, but it isn't showing them up.

Markup:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList2" runat="server" DataKeyField="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="2">
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("image1", "{0}") %>' data-lightbox="imageset" Height="150px" Width="150px" ImageHeight="150px" ImageWidth="150px" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("image1", "{0}") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
                    </td>
                    <td width="600px"><asp:Label ID="nazwaLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("nazwa") %>' CssClass="produktNazwa" />
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="cenaLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("cena", "{0} PLN") %>' CssClass="produktCena" /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("image2", "{0}") %>' data-lightbox="imageset" Height="150px" Width="150px" ImageHeight="150px" ImageWidth="150px" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("image2", "{0}") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
                    </td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="opisLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("opis") %>' CssClass="produktOpis" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink5" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("image3", "{0}") %>' data-lightbox="imageset" Height="150px" Width="150px" ImageHeight="150px" ImageWidth="150px" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("image3", "{0}") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>


<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Produkty] WHERE ([ID] = @ID)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Label1" Name="ID" PropertyName="Text" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You have a query `SELECT * FROM [Produkty] WHERE ([ID] = @ID)` which obviously returns just a single result.

Comment: Yes, but it's returning all 3 colums foreach Product. So i should have access to these image1,2 and 3. But how can I access this? It's returning it's url paths fine, but doesnt show the image itself.

Comment: From what I can see here, I have to agree with @dotnetom . Assuming ID is a value which is unique to each entry(eg a key or pseudo key), this type of query could only ever return 1 row. As you sure your query is correct???

Comment: I think you will need to show us a sample of the data scheme being returned, eg the 3 columns and an example of their typical data.

Comment: Hyperlink's are bounded to other columns of the row. It's displaying correctly other data such as ProductName, Description, Price and so on, but doesnt show image2 and imgae3, but it reads the url to them correctly.

Comment: Ok. The problem was in format of the picture. I've uploaded an .png images as second and third. I checked uploading an .jpg images as 1,2,3 and everything works perfect. They are showing correctly. But im curious why isnt it showing only the .png files... Any ideas?